# Jquery/CSS Content slider

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me which slider is this? Or can provide me the link of the slider below:

[image]

Comment: Which website is that?

Comment: That's not developed yet.. I got PSD which I need to convert to HTML... So, its only a part of PSD file.. If it was website, I could have figured it out myself :)

Comment: Then that exact slider might not exist. Grab any generic slider, and customize it to look that way.